# QuickBlox ios API: turn off debug message

Tags: quickblox

Hi is there a way to turn off the QuickBlox iOS API message output on the console? I mean like the URLs and the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set log level via QBSettings. (http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Classes/QBSettings.html#//api/name/setLogLevel:)

```
[QBSettings setLogLevel: QBLogLevelNothing];
```